# Can only access my webserver from my computer?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I am learning Apache2, and I just attempted to make my local web server live to the internet.

When I type my IP 86.207.14.136 on the browser's address bar and access it, I see the index.html stored in /var/www. And that's exactly what is supposed to happen.

Problem is, when I try to access it from an anonymous web proxy such as webproxy.ca or any other, I can't see my webpage.

Can anyone please tell if I'm doing something wrong?

My IP address is 186.207.14.136/

```
traceroute 200.228.244.6 output:
traceroute to 200.228.244.6 (200.228.244.6), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  3.123 ms  4.779 ms  5.353 ms
 2  10.14.0.1 (10.14.0.1)  13.232 ms  17.436 ms  17.788 ms
 3  bb160001.virtua.com.br (187.22.0.1)  18.179 ms * *
```

Comment: You have to "tell" your router which device to send outside traffic too. Right now your accessing your IP externally, but your router doesn't know WHICH computer on your network it should be connecting you to. You need to open the port on your router and forward it to the local IP of your server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. I already did that. I went into 'Virtual Server' settings and fowarded the 80 Port to my computer. Before I did that, I couldnt access my apache by typing my ip, but now I can. But Iam not having success when I try to access it from other computers.

Comment: Connecting to 186.207.14.136:80... failed: Connection timed out.

Comment: From my IP address I can't come past: ` 13  bb160006.virtua.com.br (187.22.0.6)  376.304 ms  375.065 ms  375.200 ms`, which is an IP that belongs to your provider. But I am unsure how many hops are left to your IP address. Some providers block port 80 in their corporate firewall, did you check their policy?

Comment: Can you add the output to traceroute 200.228.244.6 to your question? That is about where I loose track of the hops: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MAcJ0.png

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but can you please tell me how I can 'add the output to tracerout 200.228.244.6 to my question'?

Comment: Just click `edit` right below your question

Comment: Just done it. How can this help?

Comment: You only added the command, not the actual output.  Please read my answer below, since i think your issue is a port-forwarding / firewall issue.

Comment: Just added the output to the question.

Comment: You have to wait a little while until 200.228.244.6 answers. That way we know how many hops are in between. On the other hand, `10.14.0.1` indicates that your ISP is using private space IP-addresses internally, which may very well mean that they won't/can't support customer side webservers.

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: Oh and btw, I read somewhere that I need to use the 'Listen' directive in the config files. I tried typing Listen 80 inside the virtualhost config but then apache failed to start. I'm afraid this directive isnt placed anywhere. Where exactly should I place it?

Comment: What does `netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep :80` output?

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: Does this mean its not correctly configured?

Comment: It means it is listening on all interfaces, which is *good* in most cases.

Comment: Check with your ISP if they support a home webserver. I am really worried about that since I saw the private space address in your traceroute.

Comment: Just called them. They told me it does have support to home webserver. I wonder what it's going on.... Can we go on VNC so you can see my router settings?

Answer (score 3):

Did you open the port on your firewall?

Comment: How can I check that? Doesn't the port become open when I make Apache listen to it? Can you please confirm if you see anything when you access http://186.207.14.136/ ?

Comment: You have to explicitly do that, Apache won't do it for you (which is a good thing security-wise). I cannot connect to your webserver, so you probably still don't have port forwarding in place.

Answer (score 2):

First off you need to open the port in your firewall or router.

**If you're on a home network, and are behind a router, you'll need to portforward.**  [This site](http://portforward.com/) can help you figure out your router's configuration for port forwarding.  For web pages, forward `TCP 80` to the system behind the router.

<sub>*If you later encounter issues with your web server not transmitting data or something, try adding in a rule for `UDP 80` to the portforwarding/firewall*</sub>

**If your connection is directly to the internet, and not behind a router, or you've already port-forwarded and it's still not working**, start by checking the configuration of your firewall.  You can do this easily by doing `sudo iptables -L -v`.  (Pastebin the result and comment here if you want me to read through it).  If there's a default "DROP" policy, or there's no reference of "ACCEPT" anywhere in the output, i can help you with that if you include the results of said command I just gave you.

Comment: Good answer, but why udp/80?

Comment: The HTTP protocol also uses UDP in rare cases.  for accurate operation for certain actions (i don't know the RFC for HTTP offhand, but i know for a fact it references UDP), UDP should usually be opened on port 80.

Comment: Not saying it is untrue, but I never heard it before, also my Apache certainly isn't listening on port udp/80.

Comment: Then its irrelevant, although i've read the RFC.  I'll remove it, but add it as a footnote saying "If stuff breaks, try adding in a `UDP 80` rule."

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. Sorry for not making it clear, I'm actually behind a router. I already went into the my router web-based settings, and did what the tutorial told me to. Still can't access apache from other computers.

Comment: @user1091856 Did you check to see if there're any firewall rules in place on your computer itself?  Did you also check to see whether or not your ISP blocks port 80 inbound to your network?  Some ISPs do that to prevent you from running web servers

Answer (score 2):

What type of router do you have?

Have you added a NAT rule to say that all traffic coming to port 80 on your public IP address should be directed to the computer running the Apache web server on your network?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. My wireless router is a D-Link DI-524. What I've done is this: I started apache2, made it listen to port 80, then went into my router settings page, Virtual Server settings then enabled port fowarding to the computer where apache is running. After I did this, I was able to access my webpage by typing my ip address on the browser (which wasnt possible before csetting virtual server). Problem: computers outside the LAN can't access it.

Comment: I would suggest that you call your ISP and have them test this with you.

From what I've read, you are able to access your Apache server from behind your router using the routers _public_ IP address. It's very important that this is the public IP address because that means that your router seems to be correctly configured. I will also assume that you've been able to access the Apache server from a different computer than the one running the Apache server. This is also important because it means that the firewall on the Apache server is correctly configured.

[to be continued]

Comment: [continued]
This really only leaves the ISP routing and as jippie pointed out above, they seem to have you on a private IP subnet (10.14.0.1) which means that they are doing NAT (to map 186.207.14.136 -> 10.14.0.1) but you then also want to do NAT (to map 10.14.0.1 -> 192.168.x.x, the IP of your Apache server). This sounds like a can of worms.

Call them and ask them to try to access your Apache server through both the public IP (186.207.14.136) and the private IP (10.14.0.1).

As I said, there doesn't seem to be a problem with your config so it really _must_ be the ISP.

Comment: There is one thing you could possibly try though. Instead of using your routers Virtual Server setting, try using NAT. I would even suggest that you try using a non-standard port for the public port (something above 1024) but you point it to port 80 on your server. See http://support.dlink.com/emulators/di524/help_adv.html for instructions, the section "Special Applications".

Just make sure you delete your existing Virtual Server settings first.